# Alternatives to using a repository for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ide, repository

I'm programming something by myself. All I want to do is be able to simply roll back to previous versions in case I find problems. What's something quick and simple to setup that works in Eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are talking about a version control repository, if you install the git tools on your machine you can have a local repository that allows you to rollback should it be necessary. Its not really any trouble to set it up.

```
git init
git add whatever.c
git commit -a -m "message"
```

If you're looking for something simpler than this, you won't be able to find any version control packages that work without a commit cycle. If you're looking to something that will just allow you to rollback to a set moment in time you may be better off looking for an automated backup solution every X minutes... but it won't work right in eclipse.

Comment: +1 something local like git.  If you install EGit you won't need an external git install.  The latest version will provide more functionality than the requestor needed, commits, tags, and branches.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way, one is to right click and select "restore from file history"
Or File Export project, and save it on your drive.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend investing an hour in learning the basics of source control, either GIT or Mercurial. I resisted this for a long time, thinking that it is "just me" and I don't need all that complexity.

Turns out using either was pretty simple. The GitHub site provides an excellent introduction. MercurialEclipse is also fairly straightforward AFTER you put in some upfront time learning about it.

There is an excellent primer on DVCS in general, and Mercurial specifically by Joel Spolsky (Co-founder of Stack Overflow, by-the-by) HERE:

[hgInit by Joel Spolsky](http://hginit.com/index.html)

And GitHUb is an Awesome site as well,with an excellent introduction HERE:

[GitHub](https://github.com/)

It took me a while to get it all straight (the basics) as I am completely self-taught. But I have never looked back.